# What's the best way to check if characters exist in string in SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have strings like:

```
t.reported_name
-------------------------
    D3O using TM-0549 - Rev # 6
    D3O using TM-0549 - Rev # 6
    Water using TM-0415 - Rev #10
    Water using TM-0449 - Rev # 10
    Decanoic Acid using LL-1448 - Rev# 2
    DBE-821 using QCRM-0015 - Rev#1
    Water using TM-0441 Rev # 10
    FC Sessile Drop Contact Angle using MTM-017_REV_B - Rev # 1
    IPA using QCRM-0017
    Norbloc using TM-0501 - Rev # 5
    DK (non-edge corrected) using TM-0534 - Rev # 3
    Decanoic Acid_L3 using LL-1448_L3
    Decanoic Acid_L4 using LL-1448_L4
    MXP7-1911 using CRM-0239
    TMPTMA using TM-0515 - Rev# 8
    DK (edge corrected) using MTM-09 - Rev# 0
```

I need to extract test method (anything after 'using') with  number, i.e: `TM-0549`
and Revision number, i.e: `Rev # 6`

```
select  distinct 
     case when REGEXP_LIKE(t.reported_name,'TM-', 'c') THEN SUBSTR(t.reported_name, INSTR(t.reported_name, 'TM'), 7) END test_method,
     case when INSTR(t.reported_name,'Rev #') = 1 THEN SUBSTR(t.reported_name, INSTR(t.reported_name, 'Rev'), 7) END revision_number
from test s
```

from above data I want:

```
test_method  revision_number
```

---

```
TM-0549     Rev # 6
TM-0549     Rev # 6
TM-0415     Rev #10
TM-0449     Rev # 10
LL-1448     Rev# 2
QCRM-0015   Rev#1
TM-0441     Rev # 10
MTM-017_REV_B  Rev # 1
QCRM-0017   null
TM-0501     Rev # 5
TM-0534     Rev # 3
LL-1448_L3  null
LL-1448_L4  null
CRM-0239    null
TM-0515     Rev# 8
MTM-09      Rev# 0
```

Comment: Why instr doesn't work? instr(reported_name, 'TM-') > 0 is not working?

Comment: @vav actually it works. I said = 1 instead of > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

- for test_method, we want to match `TM-<number>`
- for revision, we want to match `Rev # <number>` (note the spaces around #)

Then here's a solution with `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
select 
  regexp_substr(reported_name, 'TM\-[0-9]+') as test_method_regexsub,
  regexp_substr(reported_name, 'Rev # [0-9]+') as revision_regexsub            
from test t
```

And here's another one with `REGEXP_REPLACE`; we have to use the CASE/REGEXP_LIKE workaround to return an empty string if the regex doesn't match, because REGEXP_REPLACE returns the whole string unchanged if no match is found:

```
select 
  (case 
     when regexp_like(reported_name, '.*(TM\-[0-9]+).*') 
     then regexp_replace(reported_name, '.*(TM\-[0-9]+).*', '\1') 
     else '' 
   end)  as test_method_regexrepl,
  (case 
     when regexp_like(reported_name, '.*(Rev # [0-9]+).*') 
     then regexp_replace(reported_name, '.*(Rev # [0-9]+).*', '\1') 
     else '' 
   end)  as revision_regexrepl
from test t
```

The second approach uses a capturing group `(Rev # [0-9]+)` and replaces the whole string with its contents `\1`.

**2nd UPDATE**

Assuming

- everything in front of `using` should be ignored
- everything up to an optional `Rev` is the test method name
- a revision consists of `Rev # <number>`, where the first space is optional

this should work:

```
select reported_name,
       (case 
          when regexp_like(reported_name, '.* using (.*)( - Rev.*)') 
            then regexp_replace(reported_name, '.* using (.*)( - Rev.*)', '\1') 
          when regexp_like(reported_name, '.* using (.*)') 
            then regexp_replace(reported_name, '.* using (.*)', '\1') 
          else '' end)  as test_method_regexrepl,
       (case when regexp_like(reported_name, '.* - (Rev[ ]?# [0-9]+)') 
          then regexp_replace(reported_name, '.*(Rev[ ]?# [0-9]+)', '\1') 
          else '' end)  as revision_regexrepl
from test t
```

Explanation:

- `.* using (.*)( - Rev.*)` is our regex for a test method that has a revision. It matches

  - an arbitrary string `.*`
  - the string `using` (note the two spaces)
  - an arbitrary string `(.*)` - we use the parentheses `()` to capture this part of the match in a group
  - the string `- Rev`, followed by an arbitrary string; again, we use parentheses to capture the string in a group (although we don't really need that)

  If we have a match, we replace the whole string with the first capturing group `\1` (this contains the part between `using` and `Rev`
- `.* using (.*)` is our fallback for a test method without the revision; it matches

  - an arbitrary string `.*`
  - the string `using` (note the two spaces)
  - an arbitrary string `(.*)` - we use the parentheses `()` to capture this part of the match in a group

  If we have a match, we replace the whole string with the first capturing group `\1` (this contains the part between `using` and `Rev`
- `.* - (Rev[ ]?# [0-9]+)` is our regex for the revision part. It matches

  - an arbitrary string followed by a hyphen surrounded by spaces `.* -`
  - the word `Rev`
  - an optional space `[ ]?`
  - a lattice followed by a space `#`
  - one or more digits `[0-9]+`
    and again uses a capturing group `(Rev...)` for the "interesting" part

  If we have a match, we replace the whole string with the first capturing group `\1` (this contains the part between `Rev` and the last digit)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/30817)

Comment: I just learned that test_method is anything after 'using' and I also have cases when Rev is like: 'DAROCUR using TM-0515 - Rev# 8'

Comment: thank you so much. Do you mind throwing a word or two on what's exactly happening in here :)

Comment: Using your obve query, I noticed that in some cases, like here: 'D3O using TM-0549 Rev #4 - Analyst 1 Retest', my test_method_regexrepl comes out:'TM-0549 Rev #4 - Analyst 1 Retest', and revision_regexrepl: null. AND in case where: 'D3O using TM-0549 - Rev # 4 Analyst 2 Retest' my revision_regexrepl: 'Rev # 4 Analyst 2 Retest'

Comment: @Angelina I've added an explanation

Comment: how do I also account for when there is something after Rev # 5 ? Like here: 'D3O using TM-0549 - Rev # 4 Analyst 2 Retest', 'D3O using TM-0549 Rev #4 - Analyst 1 Retest'

Comment: or here: 'Decanoic Acid using LL - 1448 Rev #2'

Comment: @Angelina To account for an optional part after the `Rev`, just add a `.*` at the end of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

TMPTMA is not matched by your regexp, instr is working:

```
select 'regexp match' descr, count(*) 
from dual where regexp_like('TM-PTMA', 'TM-') 
union all
select 'regexp no match', count(*) 
from dual where regexp_like('TMPTMA', 'TM-') 
union all
select 'instr no match', count(*) 
from dual where instr('TMPTMA', 'TM-') > 0
union all
select 'instr match', count(*) 
from dual where instr('TM-PTMA', 'TM-') > 0
```

Output:

```
DESCR             COUNT(*)
--------------- ----------
regexp match             1 
regexp no match          0 
instr no match           0 
instr match              1
```

Answer (score 1):

As for me for particular situation query can look like:

```
WITH j
     AS (SELECT 'D3O using TM-0549 - Rev # 6' str FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'D3O using TM-0549 - Rev # 6' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Water using TM-0415 - Rev #10' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Water using TM-0449 - Rev # 10' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Decanoic Acid using LL-1448 - Rev# 2' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'DBE-821 using QCRM-0015 - Rev#1' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Water using TM-0441 Rev # 10' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'FC Sessile Drop Contact Angle using MTM-017_REV_B - Rev # 1' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'IPA using QCRM-0017' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Norbloc using TM-0501 - Rev # 5' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'DK (non-edge corrected) using TM-0534 - Rev # 3' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Decanoic Acid_L3 using LL-1448_L3' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Decanoic Acid_L4 using LL-1448_L4' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'MXP7-1911 using CRM-0239' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'TMPTMA using TM-0515 - Rev# 8' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'DK (edge corrected) using MTM-09 - Rev# 0' FROM DUAL)

SELECT TRIM(RTRIM(TRIM (SUBSTR (clear_str, 0, INSTR (clear_str, ' ') + LENGTH (' '))),'-')) AS left_str,
       TRIM(LTRIM(TRIM (SUBSTR (clear_str, INSTR (clear_str, ' ') + LENGTH (' '))),'-')) AS right_str
  FROM (SELECT TRIM (SUBSTR (str, INSTR (str, 'using') + LENGTH ('using'))) || ' ' clear_str FROM j)
```

**UPD.**
Also, this solutions not depends on business data like 'Rev' or something else. But it is sensitive to spaces in our test_method value